# web2py - programmatically insert on one-to-many db

Tags: sql, database, data-access-layer, web2py, relational

Goodmorning,
I've a DB with three tables :

```
db.define_table('person',
            Field('name', length=100),
            Field('dob', length=10),
            Field('address', 'text', length=255),
            Field('countryname', length=3),
            Field('statename', length=100),
            )

db.define_table('opslist',
            Field('opid', length=10),
            Field('dop', length=10),
            Field('type_operation', length=25),
            )

db.define_table('cardlist',
            Field('opid', db.opslist),
            Field('name', db.person),
            Field('countryname', length=3, required=True),
            Field('statename', length=100, required=True),
            Field('zip', length=5, required=False),
            )
```

I would insert by code, means not using a sqlform or a form, some data into ...
e.g.: If i have all the values insertable into cardlist table the operation must give me the ability to fill automatically  the  related record (creating new if not present) into the other tables.
This because it's a relational db with foreign keys ...

Is this possible with web2py using the DAL ? or do i have to write my raw sql command ?

Thank You All

Comment: Are you saying you have the data for a person, an opslist, and a related cardlist record, but you don't know whether the person and opslist records yet exist (so they may or may not have to be created before inserting the cardlist record)? Assuming you have the person and opslist data, how do you know they can be used to identify a single unique record in each table (your person and opslist model definitions don't seem to include any uniqueness contraints)? Without the guarantee of a unique record, there's no way to know what ID to enter in the reference field in cardlist.

Comment: Hi Antony, sorry but i believe i wasn't able to explain perfectly. I would put new information : person (name etc. for person table), operation event (opslist table) and countryname, statename zip for the cardlist table. In this case in wich way i can put this info into the db ? without using sqlform or a form ? for example using : db.cardlist.insert(name = <name>, opid = <opidvalue>, countryname = <italy>, state = <italy>, zip = <12345>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`insert`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#insert) method. It returns the ID of the newly created record, which you can use to insert into the reference fields:

```
person = db.person.insert(name=..., dob=..., ...)
opslist = db.opslist.insert(opid=..., dop=..., ...)
db.cardlist.insert(opid=opslist, name=person, ...)
```